# Using Javascript on Ruby on rails and editing the code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to modify a code in Javascript. My application is written is Ruby rails and Javascript. It is run in Heroku. I have been modifiying everything in Notepadd++, then I saved it, push it into heroku and then I see the results.

The problem comes when I want to change something in Javascript. I have been making changes in a file called quote.js but when I change something, nothing happens. Below you can see the code I am trying to change. I this case I am just trying to take out a column called items from the labour summary table, I removed it from the variable dest and I put it in comments in labour summary.

It seems that the changes I make here have not any effect on the whole application. Am I modifying the wrong file?

Is this the right way to modify the javascript code in Ruby rails?

Thanks.

```
var labour_summary = $(labour_line_items).inject({}, function(sum){
            var key = this.pieceIdentifier();
            var added = this.pieceSummary();
            if(typeof sum[key] == 'undefined') {
                // New material in summary
                sum[key] = added;
            } else {
                // Add quantity to summary
                sum[key].hours  += added.hours;
                sum[key].cost   += added.cost;
                //sum[key].item += ", " + added.item;
            }
            return sum;
        });


        var dest = this.labour_summary_table;
        $("tr:gt(0)", dest).remove();
        $.each(labour_summary, function() {
            dest.append("<tr><td>" + [$.round_two(this.hours), $.dollars(this.hourly_rate), $.dollars(this.cost)].join("</td><td>") + "</td></tr>");
        });
    },
    updateCustomSummary: function(e) {
        var custom_line_items = this.activeQuoteItems().inject([], function(is) { 
                return $.merge(is, $(this).obj().activeCustomLineItems().get()); // grab this quote items labour line items
            }).collect( function() {    
                return $(this).obj();                                       // extend the array and collect the labour line item objects
            });

        var custom_summary = $(custom_line_items).inject({}, function(sum){
            var key = this.pieceIdentifier();
            var added = this.pieceSummary();
            if(typeof sum[key] == 'undefined') {
                // New material in summary
                sum[key] = added;
            } else {
                // Add quantity to summary
                sum[key].quantity   += added.quantity;
                sum[key].cost       += added.cost;
                //sum[key].item     += ", " + added.item;
            }
            return sum;
        });

        var dest = this.custom_summary_table;
        $("tr:gt(0)", dest).remove();
        $.each(custom_summary, function() {
            dest.append("<tr><td>" + [this.customName, this.quantity, $.dollars(this.costPerPiece), $.dollars(this.cost), this.item].join("</td><td>") + "</td></tr>");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Java or javascript?  They are not the same thing at all.

Comment: is quote.js actually being included in your layout?

Comment: Sorry. Everything is javascript. Quote.js is in public\javascripts\modules\ I don't see any reference in the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are including the javascript file quote.js on the page you are trying to load.(Use firebug addon for firefox under net tab or script tab to check if the file is loaded or not). You need to include javascript in your layout.

Comment: Just include the javascript file in layout to load quote.js

Comment: Hello Jawad. It seems it is loading something called based_package.js This file seems is not updated when I change the actual quote.js. If I am editing it with notepad++, how can I change it? this file is very complex to read and edit. Thanks.

Comment: You need to go to your application app/views/layouts folder and in the application.html.erb file in the head section you need to include your quote.js. You can do this by adding <%= javascript_include_tag "main" %> in the head section. This way every time your page loads your js will be loaded as well and you will be able to see changes related to javascript on the page.